# Scala class extends Java class

Tags: java, scala, class, overriding, extending

I'm a little new to this, so sorry if it may seem a naive question. Let's say I have Java class as follows:

```
public class A {
      private final regex = "folder1/folder2/folder3/.*";
      private Pattern pattern;
      
      A(...) {
       this.pattern = Pattern.Compile(regex)
      }


      public func1(String str){
        if (...){
          Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str)
        }  
      }
}
```

now I'm trying to extend the class `A` with scala so I can override the `regex` field and therefore the `pattern` field following with it.

```
class B(...) extends A(...){
}
```

But I'm not sure how to override the regex to be `regex = "folder4/.*"` for class `B`

Comment: You cannot override private members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it into a protected constructor:

```
class A {
    private final String regex;

    protected A(String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    public A() {
        this("folder1/folder2/folder3/.*");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super("folder4/.*");
    }
}
```

Or just declare each as a constant and use an overrideable method to read them:

```
class A {
    private static final String REGEX = "folder1/folder2/folder3/.*";
    
    protected String getRegex() {
        return REGEX;
    }
}

class B {
    private static final String REGEX = "folder4/.*";
    
    @Override
    protected String getRegex() {
        return REGEX;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to not pass it to the constructor? it's fine if the ```regex``` be public

Comment: If it’s `final`, making it `public` wouldn’t make a difference. If you add `public` *and* take away `final`, it can be changed from anywhere at any time. This isn’t really specific to Scala extending a Java class. The same applies for Java extending Java or Scala extending Scala.