# Scala overriding Java fields and members

Tags: java, regex, scala, overriding, extend

I'm trying to extend the class `A` which is written in Java to class `B` in Scala.

```
class A { 
    private Pattern pattern;
    private String regex= "folder1/folder2/folder3/.*";
    A(...){
       this.regex = regex;
       this.pattern = Pattern.compile(getRegex());
    }
    
    
    public String getRegex() {
        return regex;
    }
}

class B(...) extends A(...) {
    val regex: String= "folder4/.*";
    
    override def getRegex(): String = {
        return regex;
    }
}
```

However it seems that the `Pattern.compile(getRegex())` is getting `null` value from the `B` class. I'm also not allowed to pass the override regex through the constructor. Not sure how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala class extends Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269318/scala-class-extends-java-class)

Comment: @LeviRamsey Isn't the question different?

Comment: @AliDavoodiMoghadam *"I'm also not allowed to pass the override regex through the constructor"* Why?

Comment: Cross-published at https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/yistel/scala_overriding_java_fields_and_members/

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with scala specifically.

The `regex` instance variable you create in class `B` is initialized at some point. Unfortunately, that point is *after* `A`'s constructor runs.

In general, when a constuctor in `Parent` invokes an instance method that is overridden in `Child`, all heck breaks loose. Doesn't matter if it's all java, all scala, or a combination of the two.

There are a few solutions. The simplest is to simply get rid of that field. If the `getRegex()` method instead is written as `return "folder4/.*"` instead of `return regex`, this problem won't occur.

Answer (score 0):

See [Java order of Initialization and Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093470/java-order-of-initialization-and-instantiation)

The constructor is executed at the step 3

> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using `this`). If this constructor is for a class other than `Object`, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using `super`). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.

And an instance field is initialized at the step 4

> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.

So at the step 3 in the line `this.pattern = Pattern.compile(getRegex())` inside the constructor of `A`, `getRegex()` returns `regex`, which is `null` at the moment (`regex` will become `"folder1/folder2/folder3/.*"` later, at the step 4).